# How to activate all hidden gameObjects in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, menu

I'm making a menu for a game in unity. I have created text and buttons which have functions that open panels with more options in the menu. For example, click on the options button and a new box will appear, which has been hidden by unticking the box in the top left of inspector of that object and using the setActive boolean, on click to activate it during run time.

The program works perfectly. However, if I want to edit the object that is hidden when editing the menu in unity, I have to tick the box top left in the inspector to therefore see it. This is only a minor problem however, if I want to run the program to check for errors I need to find each and every object that has to be unticked again.

Is there a way of seeing that object without me re-ticking the box in the editor of unity as I can see mistakes being made as I implement more boxes?

Comment: I would make prefabs of them. This way you can leave them disabled in the scene but go to [prefab edit mode](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/EditingInPrefabMode.html) where it can be active and you can edit it. The other advantage of this is that your boxes and buttons become reusable and you have to make changes only in the prefab template and all instances will get updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the void Start() you should deactivate that UI:

```
void Start()
{
  text1.setActive(false);
  img2.setActive(false);
   //and so on
 }
```

In this way, you can have all objects activated in the scene when you are trying or modifying them it will not cause problems at the start of the program.